# how to properly split string to create dictionary in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I have two Strings

> "*TOP* : Cotton + Embroidered ( 2 Mtr) \n*BOTTOM* : Cotton + Solid (2
> Mtr) \n*DUPATTA* : Chiffon + Lace Work ( 2 Mtr) \n*TYPE* :  Un
> Stitched\n*COLOUR* : Multi Colour \n*CONTAINS* : 1 TOP WITH LINING 1
> BOTTOM & 1 DUPATTA\nCountry of Origin: India"

and Second one is

> "Top Fabric: Cotton Cambric + Top Length: 0-2.00\nBottom Fabric:
> Cotton Cambric + Bottom Length: 0-2.00\nDupatta Fabric: Nazneen +
> Dupatta Length: 0-2.00\nLining Fabric: Cotton Cambric\nType: Un
> Stitched\nPattern: Printed\nMultipack: 3 Top\nCountry of Origin:
> India"

I need to create python dictionary out of these two strings but with keys which are before colon

for example in **string one**
keys would be

> TOP,BOTTOM,DUPATTA,TYPE,COLOUR,CONTAINS,COUNTRY OF ORIGIN

and in **second one**

keys would be

> Top Fabric,Bottom Fabric,Top Length,Bottom Length,Dupatta
> Fabric,Dupatta Length,Lining Fabric,Type,Pattern,Multipack,Country of
> Origin

So far i have used

```
keys = ["Top Fabric","Bottom Fabric","Dupatta Fabric","Lining Fabric","Type","Pattern","Multipack","TOP ","BOTTOM ","  DUPATTA ","COLOUR ","CONTAINS ","TYPE ","Country"] 

pattern = re.compile('({})\s+'.format(':|'.join(keys))) 
newdict = dict(zip(*[(i.strip() for i in (pattern.split(desc.replace("*",""))) if i)]*2))
```

but it is not working on first string and on second string it is  not creatng every key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a regex pattern that matches the part before the colon in group 1 and after the colon in group 2.

Then assert that after group 2, there is either another part starting with a `+` followed by `:` or the end of the string.

Then create a dictionary, stripping the group 1 and group 2 values.

```
(?:\s*\+\s*)?([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^:]+)(?=\+[^:+]*:|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\s*\+\s*)?` Optionally match a `+` sign between optional whitespace chars
- `([^:]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except `:`
- `\s*:\s*` Match a `:` between optional whitespace chars
- `([^:]+)` Capture **group 2**, match any char except `:`
- `(?=\+[^:+]*:|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either `+` followed by `:` to the right, or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x1i0Dy/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5jpk7p)

Example

```
import re
import pprint

pattern = r"(?:\s*\+\s*)?([^:\r\n]+)\s*:\s*([^:\r\n]+)\s*(?=\+[^:+\n]*:|$)"

s = ("TOP : Cotton + Embroidered ( 2 Mtr) \n"
            "BOTTOM : Cotton + Solid (2 Mtr) \n"
            "DUPATTA : Chiffon + Lace Work ( 2 Mtr) \n"
            "TYPE : Un Stitched\n"
            "COLOUR : Multi Colour \n"
            "CONTAINS : 1 TOP WITH LINING 1 BOTTOM & 1 DUPATTA\n"
            "Country of Origin: India\n\n"
            "Top Fabric: Cotton Cambric + Top Length: 0-2.00\n"
            "Bottom Fabric: Cotton Cambric + Bottom Length: 0-2.00\n"
            "Dupatta Fabric: Nazneen + Dupatta Length: 0-2.00\n"
            "Lining Fabric: Cotton Cambric\n"
            "Type: Un Stitched\n"
            "Pattern: Printed\n"
            "Multipack: 3 Top\n"
            "Country of Origin: India")

dictionary = {}
for m in re.finditer(pattern, s, re.MULTILINE):
    dictionary[m.group(1).strip()] = m.group(2).strip()
pprint.pprint(dictionary)
```

Output

```
{'BOTTOM': 'Cotton + Solid (2 Mtr)',
 'Bottom Fabric': 'Cotton Cambric',
 'Bottom Length': '0-2.00',
 'COLOUR': 'Multi Colour',
 'CONTAINS': '1 TOP WITH LINING 1 BOTTOM & 1 DUPATTA',
 'Country of Origin': 'India',
 'DUPATTA': 'Chiffon + Lace Work ( 2 Mtr)',
 'Dupatta Fabric': 'Nazneen',
 'Dupatta Length': '0-2.00',
 'Lining Fabric': 'Cotton Cambric',
 'Multipack': '3 Top',
 'Pattern': 'Printed',
 'TOP': 'Cotton + Embroidered ( 2 Mtr)',
 'TYPE': 'Un Stitched',
 'Top Fabric': 'Cotton Cambric',
 'Top Length': '0-2.00',
 'Type': 'Un Stitched'}
```

Comment: Hi, I will keep my both strings separate. So at a time, i will run only one string, your code works well for the Second String but not giving a result for the first string

This is first String...

"TOP : Cotton + Embroidered ( 2 Mtr) \nBOTTOM : Cotton + Solid (2 Mtr) \nDUPATTA : Chiffon + Lace Work ( 2 Mtr) \nTYPE : Un Stitched\nCOLOUR : Multi Colour \nCONTAINS : 1 TOP WITH LINING 1 BOTTOM & 1 DUPATTA\nCountry of Origin: India"

Comment: @James I think it looks ok right? https://regex101.com/r/419qwo/1 See this python demo https://ideone.com/84IwdH

Answer (score 1):

You may try below dict comprehension, s1 represents one of your strings:

```
d={i.split(':')[0].strip(): i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in s1.split('\n')}
```

Edited:
To make combining dict easier you can define a function:

```
def f(s1):
    return {i.split(':')[0].strip(): i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in s1.split('\n')}
f('\n'.join([s1,s2])) # single dict from both strings
set(f(s1).keys()).intersection(f(s2).keys()) # common keys
```

{'Country of Origin'} key common key in both sets, but it eeuals India

Comment: Hello your code works well with second string but not giving result for first string

Comment: Have a look at update answer, please specify what goes wrong with first string conversion.